# Php Slugifiy function returned value is different in 2 servers

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace, slugify

This is my `slugify` function:

```
function slugify($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    $text = mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8');
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
    if(empty($text)) return 'n-a';
    return $text;
}
```

This is the test:

```
echo slugify("españa");
```

In my development server the result is:

- **espana**

In my production server the result is:

- **espaa**

I'm sure it has something to do with charset encoding, but both servers have `UTF-8` as `default_charset`. What else could I be missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the `iconv` function.
In the [comments of the documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.iconv.php#74101), we can see:

> Please note that iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', ...) doesn't work properly when locale category LC_CTYPE is set to C or POSIX. You must choose another locale otherwise all non-ASCII characters will be replaced with question marks.